# install msi on TFS Build Server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I have used TFS API to develop a custom Web Application.
When I try to build the Application on the server using TFS Build, I see the
 build failing since there are no assemblies installed on the
Build Server.

I have searched online but couldnt find any. Is there an msi somewhere 
that I can install on the TFS Build Server which installs all the TFS
API assemblies on the build server ?? , instead of installing 
each and every assembly individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most teams install Visual Studio on the build server for a number of reasons.  If you do that it will include the TFS Object Model assemblies.

Comment: We already have Visual Studio Ultimate installed on the build server.

Comment: Try remoting into the build server, and opening your code in Visual Studio and building it.  If you have VS all the assemblies should be there.